# Pull chain switch for 5 bulb chandelier

Tags: electrical

I replaced a ceiling fan with a chandelier, using 5x40 watt bulbs.  But tried to put a pull chain switch since I have 3 ceiling fans on 1 switch on my covered deck.  There was a pop and the pull chain didn't work anymore.  ???? Too much wattage for the switch??? 1A/125v; 3A/250v.  Is there a pull chain switch that would work?

Comment: The current rating seems reversed to me (usually current allowed is higher at lower voltage) but 1A @ 125V would mean it could handle 125 watts. Yes, you can find some that have more current. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-6-3-Amp-Single-Pole-Single-Circuit-Pull-Chain-Switch-Nickel-plating-GSW-31/100126308

Comment: Check for short-circuited lamp wiring before sacrificing a bigger pull-chain.

Comment: The first switch was under rated the one topshhot linked should work+